# How can a resonance circuit work as a current amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, soldering, preamp

I have been working on current amplifiers for my RF circuit. I was thinking about pre-amplifying the current by a tank circuit. The input of the circuit is just a mp3 player, which has not much current, so I looked up for the frequency, which was 128k for the output. I calculated a tank circuit with this given frequency, and I have seen it takes a capacitor of 103nF and an inductor of 15uH. I placed a resistor of 10 ohm at the end. I had no 1nF capacitors, so I managed to reduce the capacitor to 100nF. It gave good result in simulation software like illustrated below. The amperemeter can be replaced with a headphone, for example. I measured the current between input (green line) and output (red line) of the circuit in simulation and I saw there is a big gain for current at output.  As I soldered the components together and tested it at workplace, I had a less sound quality, and the result was almost the same as the output of sound from mp3 player. My question is that, if I pre-amplified and soldered the right way and if there are differences between reality and the outputs of simulation software?

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The input of the circuit is just a mp3 player, which has not much
> current, so I looked up for the frequency, which was 128k for the
> output.*

Your MP3 player's audio output is limited to below 20 kHz. The 128 kHz you mention is the bit rate at which the data is fed to the MP3 decoder. The decoder outputs audio ranging from about 20 Hz to a few kHz below 20 kHz i.e. the audible range for humans.

If you want to amplify audio (a wide range of sounds and frequencies limited to a little below 20 kHz), you need an amplifier and not a tuned circuit.

> *My question is that, if I pre-amplified and soldered the right way and
> if there are differences between reality and the outputs of simulation
> software?*

It has nothing to do with this; it's your incorrect interpretation of what the output spectrum is.

> *How can a resonance circuit work as a current amplifier?*

It only does so over a very limited range of frequencies i.e. those frequencies closest to the tuned filter's frequency work best and, if you want high current amplification the range of frequencies gets smaller. It will be useless for audio.

Comment: Thanks for this informational feedback.